# Is it possible to disable an extension addin on start-up?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, add-in

I am currently creating an addin, that can be toggled on/off from the extension manager. What I want to do is when ArcMap is being loaded, to check the license level being used (which I have done), what I then would like to happen is that the extension in the Manager is disabled and the text changed to something like "xxx ArcEditor Required".

Is this possible to do? I know I can change the name of the Extension via the config file, but can't seem to find the property to do it outside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about changing the description in the Extension manager dialogue but you can enable/disable extensions via the *State* property of the *IExtensionConfig* interface.